# How to write all_subsets function using recursion?

Tags: python, function, recursion, subset

Given the function `all_subsets(lst)`, how can I write this function using recursion?

For example of input: `[1,2,3]`, the output should be: `[[], [1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3][1,2,3]]`

The assignment is to use recursive function. Please help. This is part of a lab assignment, so I am not graded on this, but at the same time, I am dying to learn how to write this code, and I don't know anyone in my lab class that's figured it out.

So far, I've got:

```
def all_subsets(b):
    if len(b) == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        lst = []
        subsets = all_subsets(b[1:])
        for i in b:
            lst.append([i])
        for i in subsets:
            if b[0] not in i:
                lst.append([b[0]] + i)
        for i in subsets:
            if b[1] not in i:
                lst.append([b[1]] + i)
        return lst
```

It can handle `[1,2,3]`, but it can't handle anything bigger; plus this code also has weird output order

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  All questions asking for code need to show what the asker has done so far in trying to solve the problem themselves.  Afterwards, we will be more than happy to help with any specific issues you are having.

Comment: Iteration is probably more idiomatic than recursion in Python, this is a good use case for a generator.

Comment: @Paulo: Or use `itertools` for a one-liner: `itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(functools.partial(itertools.combinations, lst), range(len(lst)+1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def all_subsets(b):
    if len(b)==1:
        return [[], b]  # if set has 1 element then it has only 2 substets
    else:
       s = all_subsets(b[:-1])  # calculate subsets of set without last element
       # and compose remaining subsets
       return sorted(s + [e + [b[-1]] for e in s], key=len)  # you can omit sorting if you want
```

Comment: this will help me improve my recursive coding so much. You are the best.